# Retrieving Int Value from Parse for Xcode and displaying it in a label

Tags: xcode, parsing, integer, label

bit of a beginner here and I've been stuck on something all day!

I've got 2 Parse Tables: a User (which works perfectly for logging in etc) and a UserStats that holds variables (in this case the User's Level as the first column)

All I want to do is retrieve the User's current level and display it in a label in Xcode. I've done lots of research but I cannot work out where I've gone wrong.

I'm using this Query in my .m:

```
    - (void) retrieveFromParse { 
       PFQuery query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserStats"];
       [query whereKey:@"User" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
       [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:(PFObjectobject, NSError *error) 
         {
            if (!object) 
               {
               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oh No!" message:@"Could not locate value!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
               [alert show];
               }
            else 
               {
               int Level = [[object objectForKey:@"Level"] intValue];
               [_newlabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Level]];
               }
         }]; 
       }
```

and my .h looks like this:

```
     import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     import <Parse/Parse.h>

     @interface ShowLevel : UIViewController 

     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *newlabel;

     @end
```

Edit: I've turned on exception breakpoints and it's highlighting:

```
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
```

Comment: try turning on exception breakpoints and running it to see what line is causing the problem. http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: Okay, so the error is something to do with:
        [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been resolved. I used the .m code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserStats"];
PFObject *Object = [query getObjectWithId:@"fghsd7fddhf"];
level = [[Object objectForKey:@"Level"] intValue];
[levelLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", level]];
```

While it's only temporary since I'll need to change it to point to values without specifying objectId, this works nicely for testing. Thanks to everyone who provided help :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual error that you are getting?  Also you have to do anything that has to do with UI on the main thread.  The query is actually running on the background thread and you are either showing alertView or updating a label which you have to do on the main thread. Add `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ });` to your code where you are doing UI

```
if (!object) 
               {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oh No!" message:@"Could not locate value!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                      [alert show];
                  });
               }
            else 
               {
                          int Level = [[object objectForKey:@"Level"] intValue];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          [_newlabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Level]];
                    });
               }
```

Comment: OKAY! Still working on this same problem, but I'm getting closer. There is no errors with the program now (I went through EVERYTHING and found a few odd things that didn't match up). 
HOWEVER, now I get the error message that I coded to come up, saying it cannot retrieve the value. This leads me to think the problem is now purely to do with the retrieval method...

Comment: Do NSLog(%@, [PFUser currentUser]); at the beginning and see if that is not nil.  This way you know that you are logged in for sure.

Comment: Yep, it's logging me in fine. Still no retrieval yet, but I'll keep fiddling haha.

Comment: are you getting an error message that cannot retrieve the value or it shows the alert view because object is nil?

Comment: Object is nill... Might be linking the tables wrong or something?

Comment: Double check the database name and the user is is in the database.  I think the names are case sensitive.